# CKEditor 4 - syntaxhighlight in customised toolbar

Tags: ckeditor

*This is also posted on (http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/syntaxhighlight-in-customised-toolbar)*

I've downloaded the FULL build of CKEditor and have added the Syntaxhighlighter Interface (from http://ckeditor.com/addon/syntaxhighlight). I'm using the editor in various places of my site for different uses so want to be able to setup customised toolbars fdor each use. Having used CKEditor 3 (and FCKEditor!), I'm used to setting up named toolbars in the config.js file, but I cannot get the Syntaxhighlighter Interface button to show.

My config.toolbar code is below (notice the 'Code' button in the 'insert' toolbar) and any help would be appreciated!

```
config.toolbar = [
    { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ], items: [ 'Source', '-', 'Templates'] },
    { name: 'tools', items: [ 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks' ] },
    { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ], items: [ 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord' ] },
    { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ], items: [ 'SelectAll' ] },
    { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ] },
    { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'SpecialChar', 'Code' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ], items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ], items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
    { name: 'others', items: [ '-' ] },
];
```

Please help...